# Is continuous function $f:X=A \cup B \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ constant?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint. Let $X$ be a topological space.

Is every continuous function $f:X=A \cup B  \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ constant?

Comment: What is the topology of $\{-1,1\}$?

Comment: What is the topology of X? :)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to prove the easy, though important

**Claim:** A topological space $\,X\,$ is connected iff there is *not* a continuous *surjective* function $\,f:X\to\{0,1\}\,$ , taking $\,\{0,1\}\,$  with the inherited euclidean (i.e. the usual one) topology on $\,\Bbb R\,$

Of course, we can always take $\,\{-1,1\}\,$ instead of $\,\{0,1\}\,$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(-2,-1)$ and $B=(1,2)$. Then let $f(x)=\mbox{sign}(x)=x/|x|$. Then $f$ is continuous but not constant.